# Neo4j server refuse any connection

Tags: neo4j

I'm running neo4j v2.2.3 on linux 64bit server with 1.7.0 java.

The server suddenly refuse to connect, log:

```
>    2015-09-11 15:39:52.306+0000 INFO  [API] Remote interface ready and
> available at [http://0.0.0.0:8474/] 15:24:19.844 [qtp346100719-748140]
> WARN  org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - badMessage: 400 Illegal
> character 0x0 in state=METHOD in
> 'JRMI\x00<<<\x02K>>>b/data/transactio...\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
> for HttpChannelOverHttp@3d2ec258{r=0,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=-}
> 15:31:49.788 [qtp346100719-164] WARN 
> org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - badMessage: 400 Illegal character
> 0x0 in state=METHOD in
> 'JRMI\x00<<<\x02K>>>b/data/transactio...\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
> for HttpChannelOverHttp@26c4bd8c{r=0,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=-}
> 15:31:49.818 [qtp346100719-746043] WARN 
> org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - badMessage: 400 Illegal character
> 0x0 in state=METHOD in
> 'JRMI\x00<<<\x02K>>>b/data/transactio...\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
> for HttpChannelOverHttp@68468866{r=0,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=-}
> 15:36:19.818 [qtp346100719-753367] WARN 
> org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - badMessage: 400 Illegal character
> 0x0 in state=METHOD in
> 'JRMI\x00<<<\x02K>>>b/data/transactio...7ed9\\u4e86\\u5c0' for
> HttpChannelOverHttp@1aa7047a{r=0,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=-} 16:04:49.798
> [qtp346100719-133] WARN  org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser -
> badMessage: 400 Illegal character 0x0 in state=METHOD in
> 'JRMI\x00<<<\x02K>>>b/data/transactio...\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
> for HttpChannelOverHttp@794772f3{r=0,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=-}
```

In messages.log, lots of Transaction rolled back

```
> 015-09-12 07:43:49.779+0000 INFO  [o.n.s.r.t.TransactionRegistry]:
    > Transaction with id 1322181 has been automatically rolled back.
    > 2015-09-12 07:45:19.779+0000 INFO  [o.n.s.r.t.TransactionRegistry]:
    > Transaction with id 1328574 has been automatically rolled back.
    > 2015-09-12 07:46:49.779+0000 INFO  [o.n.s.r.t.TransactionRegistry]:
    > Transaction with id 1331830 has been automatically rolled back.
    > 2015-09-12 07:48:19.779+0000 INFO  [o.n.s.r.t.TransactionRegistry]:
    > Transaction with id 1277513 has been automatically rolled back.
    > 2015-09-12 07:49:49.780+0000 INFO  [o.n.s.r.t.TransactionRegistry]:
    > Transaction with id 1341580 has been automatically rolled back.
    > 2015-09-12 07:51:19.779+0000 INFO  [o.n.s.r.t.TransactionRegistry]:
    > Transaction with id 1344276 has been automatically rolled back.
    > 2015-09-12 07:52:49.779+0000 INFO  [o.n.s.r.t.TransactionRegistry]:
    > Transaction with id 1344423 has been automatically rolled back.
    > 2015-09-12 07:54:19.779+0000 INFO  [o.n.s.r.t.TransactionRegistry]:
    > Transaction with id 1313359 has been automatically rolled back.
    > 2015-09-12 07:55:49.779+0000 INFO  [o.n.s.r.t.TransactionRegistry]:
    > Transaction with id 1344184 has been automatically rolled back.
    > 2015-09-12 07:57:19.779+0000 INFO  [o.n.s.r.t.TransactionRegistry]:
    > Transaction with id 1287376 has been automatically rolled back.
    > 2015-09-12 07:58:49.779+0000 INFO  [o.n.s.r.t.TransactionRegistry]:
    > Transaction with id 1344379 has been automatically rolled back.
    > 2015-09-12 08:00:19.779+0000 INFO  [o.n.s.r.t.TransactionRegistry]:
    > Transaction with id 1303645 has been automatically rolled back.
    > 2015-09-12 08:01:49.779+0000 INFO  [o.n.s.r.t.TransactionRegistry]:
    > Transaction with id 1310122 has been automatically rolled back.
    > 2015-09-12 08:03:19.779+0000 INFO  [o.n.s.r.t.TransactionRegistry]:
    > Transaction with id 1326161 has been automatically rolled back.
    > 2015-09-12 08:04:49.779+0000 INFO  [o.n.s.r.t.TransactionRegistry]:
    > Transaction with id 1339052 has been automatically rolled back.
    > 2015-09-12 08:06:19.780+0000 INFO  [o.n.s.r.t.TransactionRegistry]:
    > Transaction with id 1346207 has been automatically rolled back.
    > 2015-09-12 08:07:49.780+0000 INFO  [o.n.s.r.t.TransactionRegistry]:
    > Transaction with id 1346291 has been automatically rolled back.
    > 2015-09-12 08:09:19.779+0000 INFO  [o.n.s.r.t.TransactionRegistry]:
    > Transaction with id 1319765 has been automatically rolled back.
    > 2015-09-12 08:10:49.779+0000 INFO  [o.n.s.r.t.TransactionRegistry]:
    > Transaction with id 1322974 has been automatically rolled back.
    > 2015-09-12 08:12:19.779+0000 INFO  [o.n.s.r.t.TransactionRegistry]:
    > Transaction with id 1329373 has been automatically rolled back.
    > 2015-09-12 08:13:49.779+0000 INFO  [o.n.s.r.t.TransactionRegistry]:
    > Transaction with id 1332642 has been automatically rolled back.
```

when i run :

```
$bin/neo4j-shell -p 8474
ERROR (-v for expanded information):
        Connection refused
```

Maybe restart will solve the problem,but i want to know what is the problem?

Many thanks for you time.

Comment: 1) neo4j-shell does not use the http port - typically it uses port 1337. 
2) what kind of requests are you sending to your neo4j instance? The first log snippet indicate that you send some weird packages.

Comment: because lots of write api called at one time, I can't reproduct the same error, but your answer did help me, thx

Answer (score 0):

This pretty much looks like you've tried to connect to the http port (7474 by default) using `neo4j-shell`. The shell uses a different port which defaults to 1337.